# how do i get rows for each month which contain the store with the highest number of purchases?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

how do i get rows for each month which contain the store with the highest number of purchases?

my code is:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(buyDate, '%M') as month, count(id) as numPurchases, store
from purchase, customerpurchases
where purchase.id = customerpurchases.purchaseid
group by month, store;
```

[image]

Comment: In MySQL 8+ use CTE and ROW_NUMBER (or FIRST_VALUE). In MySQL 5+ use subquery to obtain max of purchases number.

Comment: @Akina, unfortunately when doing a subquery, it counts the total of all numPuchases and lists it in a single row as 3859. Thats why i am confused on how to write a subquery that can fulfill my request. Any suggestions?

Comment: *when doing a subquery, it counts the total of all numPuchases and lists it in a single row as 3859.* You must select the month, not max value only, and group by the month... then join to  table by month and value.

Comment: @Akina, thank you for your answer, but it doesnt compile in mysql. im still getting a single row of 3859 when i enter in;
select numpurchases, DATE_FORMAT(buyDate, '%M') as month, store
from (select count(purchaseid) as numpurchases, buydate, store
from customerpurchases, purchase
where purchase.id = customerpurchases.purchaseid) as a
group by buydate;

Comment: Create a sample fiddle with some data (instead of a picture - CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) and show desured output for that data, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM purchase t1
JOIN ( SELECT t2.`month`, MAX(t2.numPurchases) numPurchases
       FROM purchase t2
       GROUP BY t2.`month` ) t3 
    ON t1.`month` = t3.`month`
   AND t1.numPurchases = t3.numPurchases
```